# Passport JS localstrategy to allow login with both email and username

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I wanted to allow users to be able to log in with both username and email. I've seen similar questions, but I don't think it works well with my case and now I'm still confused as to how to make this works.
I'm using passport js for the middleware, node js for backend.

Here's my passport middleware config which handles login by email:

```
passport.use(
  "login",
  new localStrategy(
    { usernameField: "email", passwordField: "password" },
    async (email, password, done) => {
      try {
        // Find the user associated with this email provided by the user
        const connection = getTypeORMConn();
        const userRepo = connection.getRepository(User);
        const user = await userRepo
          .createQueryBuilder("user")
          .select(["user.id"])
          .addSelect("user.email")
          .addSelect("user.passwordHash")
          .addSelect("user.isVerified")
          .where("user.email = :email", { email })
          .getOne();
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, {
            message: "User email not found (401-email)",
          });
        }
        return done(null, user, { message: "Log in successfull" });
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to check if user exists in database with email or username

```
.where("user.email = :email OR user.username = :email", { email })
```